# Access Facebook API response

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

i have a question aboput the facebook api. I am trying to acceess the id numbers of the posts on one of my pages. All that works great so far but the problem is that i can't figure out how to "access" the response object.

I call the api like so:

```
$pageid = "xxx";
$access_token = "xxx"

require_once( __DIR__.'/Facebook/autoload.php' );

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'                => 'xxx',
  'app_secret'            => 'xxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

$test = $fb->get('/'.$pageid.'/posts?fields=id', $access_token);
```

I would now like to retrieve all of the post id numbers of the response within the $test variable. Is there any way for me to access them through a for loop?

Comment: do you absolutely have to use the facebook php library, or may I answer with php curl code that will solve your problem?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I can convert the response into an array with this code:

```
$testnew = $test->getDecodedBody();
```